# If $T:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ is a linear transformation show that $T(u_1)$ and $ T(u_2)$ are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> If $T:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ is a linear transformation show that $T(u_1)$ and $ T(u_2)$ are linearly independent. Where $T(u_1) =\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $T(u_2) =\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$

I am not sure where to start with this question. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or else use the definition of linearly independent vectors.

If $T(u_1), T(u_2)$ are linearly independent, then:
$$\lambda_1 \cdot T(u_1) + \lambda_2 \cdot T(u_2 )=\vec 0 \implies \lambda_1=\lambda_2 =0 $$

Edit:

Reply to your comment:

$\begin{array}[t]{l}
\lambda_1 \cdot T(u_1)+\lambda_2 \cdot T(u_2)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\\
\lambda_1 \cdot \begin {pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end {pmatrix} + \lambda_2 \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end {pmatrix} = \begin {pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end {pmatrix}\\
\begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 \\ \lambda_2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin {pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end {pmatrix}
\end{array}$

Comment: Oh I get it so when you solve the matrix for zero... you can determine that $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ can only equal to 0. Therefore satisfying the definition correct? ha, I thought there was something special to this because it was a linear transformation... unless I am wrong in my explanation.

Comment: I guess this is what you mean.. I wrote it down in order to avoid any misunderstandings.

Comment: yup exactly what I meant thanks.

Comment: @user69001 You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If $T(u_1)$ and $T(u_2)$ are linearly dependent then there exist numbers $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ (at least, one of them nonzero) such that $$\alpha_1 T(u_1)+\alpha_2 T(u_2)=\vec{0}.$$ Is this possible?